# Error --- Docker wildfly console ports not by default

Tags: java, docker, jboss, console, wildfly

I have a problem with a docker wildfly container. The problem is the following, I want to launch the container with the different ports that are loaded by default 8080 for the application and 9090 for the console. I have managed to change the default port of the application, with this instruction

```
docker run -P -d jboss / wildfly /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
```

-P flag map any network ports inside the image it to a random high port from the range 49153 to 65535 on Docker host

But I can not access the administration console, on the other hand I have created a dockerfile with these values

```
FROM jboss / wildfly
RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin # 70365 --silent
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset = 5 "]
```

And another one by removing the offset values

```
FROM jboss / wildfly
RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin # 70365 --silent
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I can lift the container but I still do not have access to the Wildfly management console. What can I do to get the console up?

Comment: I think you need to specify the port mapping with -P, so like -P 18080:8080

Answer (score 2):

You need to sepecify the port mapping with "-p":

```
-p=[]      : Publish a container's port or a range of ports to the host
```

With **"-P" (uppercase)** option: Publish all **exposed ports** to the host interfaces.

If you still want to use "-P" option, using the Dockerfile: (add EXPOSE port for management administration console)

```
    FROM jboss/wildfly

    # Expose the ports we're interested in
    EXPOSE 9990

    RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#70365 --silent
    CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Then you can build the image:

```
 docker build --tag=jboss/wildfly-admin .
```

Run it:

```
docker run -it -P jboss/wildfly-admin
```

List containers:

```
docker container ls
```

You can get the result same here:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
91b6bc131b28        jboss/wildfly-admin   "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   13 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds       0.0.0.0:32771->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32770->9990/tcp   quirky_nightingale
```

Your container is running and expose port 32770 for management.
The administration console should be available at http://localhost:32770 (for my case)